# Area between the ROC curve and the Random Guessing Line

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, auc

**How close is my classifier to random guessing?**

I need to quantify the inability of a binary classifier to obtain better results than random guessing in a single number evaluation metric.

The random guessing line (RGL) from (0,0) to (1,1) has an AUC of 0.5. But so does the blue curve (grey area).

[image: ROC RGL]

Wouldn't it be more suitable to use the area between the RGL and the ROC-curve to estimate how "close" a classifier is to actual random guessing?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered you will be pretty far from the diagonal when you have few data points?

Comment: *Assuming the data set is big enough, so "no stair steps" and uncertainties from limited sample size.

Comment: My point being, your measure has a systematic bias on the number of data points. That's not something desirable in general.

Comment: The ROC curve should not cross below the diagonal as yours does.  This ROC implies there is a problem with your model; it is misspecified in some fundamental way (cf, [ROC curve crossing the diagonal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/54525/7290)). If your curve were always above the diagonal, the area between the ROC & the diagonal would be the same as AUC-.5.  Ie, you'd have a different number, but the same information.

Answer (score 2):

First, the 0.5 random guess line is just a visual reference, what we really want to know if how well the classifier performs overall. I'm also not sure how your proposed method would provide a different result, assuming that you subtract first section that is below the 0.5 line.

Second, the AUC also has a nice statistical property where it is equivalent to the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U Test statistic. This is the probability that the classifier will rank a randomly chosen positive instance higher than a randomly chosen negative instance.

In this case, we don't need to see the AUC value to know this is a poor classifier (and one unlikely to be seen in real life, as it implies that true positive values are consistently rated under a certain probability threshold while false positive values are more evenly distributed).

Answer (score 0):

> How close is my classifier to random guessing?

You could **test** this by using **Kolmogorov-Smirnov**.

*In Python:*

```
from scipy import stats

stats.ks_2samp(actual, preds)
```

Small *K-S statistic* and high *p-value* suggest that your classifier is no better than random.

(Also this might help: [How to determine whether a classifier is significantly better than random guessing?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368176/how-to-determine-whether-a-classifier-is-significantly-better-than-random-guessi))

Comment: Does class imbalance affect the k-s statistic?